# Checking if Mod_Rewrite is Enabled Remotely

Tags: apache

When pentesting it is useful to know when apache mod_rewrite is enabled. But when one comes across a web server that does not utilize PHP it is difficult to tell if mod_rewrite is enabled considering that URL redirection isn't very necessary. Is there any way to tell if it is enabled (remotely) without simply guessing common URL redirections?

Comment: "*When pentesting it is useful to know when apache mod_rewrite is enabled*". Could you clarify where this comes from? Ideally, a well-configured `mod_rewrite` (especially in the rewrite, not redirect sense) shouldn't be detectable: it should only affect the internal dispatch of the request, shouldn't it?

Comment: Exploits that rely on mod_rewrite being enabled like www.securityfocus.com/bid/19204. One ideally wouldn't want to run such an exploit during a pentest unless you were sure mod_rewrite was enabled.

Comment: Agreed. If they didn't leave the version string in the responses (eg: ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod) or mod_status enabled you shouldn't be able to tell.

Comment: Ah yes, but that's more of a `mod_rewrite` implementation bug than a problem with the fact that `mod_rewrite` and its features are used. This could happen to any piece of software. The fact that `mod_rewrite` is enabled isn't a problem, is it? (The fact that a buggy version of it is used is.)

Comment: Yes but in the case that a buggy version of it is used, mod_rewrite needs to nonetheless be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to test for poorly configured mod_rewrite configurations.

- [Metasploit](http://metasploit.com/modules/auxiliary/scanner/http/rewrite_proxy_bypass) Proxy Bypass Scanner
- [Metasploit](http://www.metasploit.com/modules/exploit/windows/http/apache_mod_rewrite_ldap) LDAP BO
- [w3af](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.security.w3af.user/page=19) has a bug that doesn't handle mod-rewrite properly, so you can end up leveraging the bug to fuzz a site to determine if it has mod_rewrite enabled

Of course, these are probes that only work if mod_rewrite exists and is unpatched and configured in a certain way.

Otherwise, I'm not sure if one could detect what is supposed to be transparent...